# Adding unnumbered amount of objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist, tree

I have a problem that I can't get around how to solve, I'm currently working on a mini filesystem wich requiers to create an massive amount of objects (in theory). I currently tried `ArrayList<INode> nodes = new ArrayList<INode>();` and then when I add an object(INode) `nodes.add(new INodeDirectory(paths[i]));`

But when I check later if this node excist in `nodes`it doesent, any suggestions on how to solve this or what to use instead?

MiniFs class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdOut;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MiniFs implements FileSystem {

  private final INodeDirectory root;
  private HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  private int n = 0; //Number of objects created
  priate ArrayList<INode> nodes = new ArrayList<INode>();

  public MiniFs() {
    root = new INodeDirectory("/");
    map.put("/",n);
  }
  //Create a directory/folder
  @Override
  public void mkdir(String path) {
    String paths[] = path.split("/");
    if(paths.length == 2){
        nodes.add(new INode<directory(paths[paths.length - 1]));
        n++;
        map.put(paths[1],n);
        StdOut.println("OK.");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 1; i < paths.length; i++){
            if(i == paths.length - 1){
                if(map.containsKey(paths[i])){
                    StdOut.println("Directory already excists");
                }
                else{
                    nodes.add(new INodeDirectory(paths[i]));
                    n++;
                    map.put(paths[i],n);
                    StdOut.println("OK.");
                }
            }
            else if(map.containsKey(paths[i]) == false){
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error: you have to create " + paths[i] + " first!");
            }
        }
    }
  }
  //Create a file
  @Override
  public void touch(String path) {
    String paths[] = path.split("/");
    if(paths.length == 2){
        nodes.add(new INodeFile(paths[paths.length - 1]));
        n++;
        map.put(paths[paths.length - 1], n);
        StdOut.println("OK.");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 1; i < paths.length; i++){
            if(i == paths.length - 1){
                if(map.containsKey(paths[i])){
                    StdOut.println("File already excists");
                } 
                else{
                    nodes.add(new INodeFile(paths[i]));
                    n++;
                    map.put(paths[i],n);
                    StdOut.println("OK.");
                }
            }
            else if(map.containsKey(paths[i]) == false){
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You have to create " + paths[i] + " first!");
            }
        }
    }
  }
  //Create a pointer to a file or directory
  @Override
  public void ln (String path, String target){
      String paths[] = path.split("/");
      String targets[] = target.split("/");
      if(paths.length == 2 && targets.length == 2 && map.containsKey(paths[1]) && map.containsKey(targets[1])){
          int pathIndex = nodes.indexOf(paths[1]);
          int targetIndex = nodes.indexOf(targets[1]);
          nodes.get(pathIndex).setPointer(nodes.get(targetIndex));
          StdOut.println("OK.");
      }
  }
}
```

INode class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

public abstract class INode {

  private String name;
  private ArrayList<INode> pointer;
  private long accessTime;

  public INode(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accessTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public void setPointer(INode n) {
      pointer.add(n);
  }

  public long getAccessTime() {
    return accessTime;
  }

  public void setAccessTime(long accessTime) {
    this.accessTime = accessTime;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

INodeDirectory class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

public class INodeDirectory extends INode {

  public INodeDirectory(String name) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

INodeFile class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

public class INodeFile extends INode {

  public INodeFile(String name) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: As you didn't override the equals method in your INode class, I don't expect contains to work (unless you use it with the same reference with the object you want to check if the list contains it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `.equals()` for anything that you're putting into an `ArrayList` and checking with `.contains()` or `.indexOf()`.

It's very easy to get your IDE to help with this. I'd strongly recommend implementing `.hashCode()` as well, in case you want to use a `HashMap` later on (otherwise you'll hit a similar problem).

You have an even more serious problem, though, which is that when you check whether it's in there, you're passing a `String` to `indexOf()` rather than an `INode`. This will fail because the list doesn't store strings. If you want to check whether a node is there, you need to create a new node from the `String`, and check whether that's present.

Comment: but I'm not realy using `.contains()`on my `ArrayList`, or is it "secretly" using `.contains()` when I'm using `.getIndexOf()`?

Comment: [`indexOf()` uses `equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) to find the element, if any.

Comment: By the way, I would strongly advise against creating an `equals()` method that would allow comparing an `INode` to a `String` as it would violate the [*symmetric* clause of the equals() contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: I'm using netBeans as my IDE and the generated `equals()`does not solve the problem, it's still not finding my objects

Comment: @Necrozze I've updated the answer to mention `.indexOf()` as well, but same principle.

Comment: @Necrozze ah, see further update. You have another major problem to address!

Comment: Clever, however it's still not finding it. Is it because I'm creating them as either `INodeDirectory` or `INodeFile` even though they are extending `INode`?

Comment: @Necrozze yes, they'll need to be the exact same type! You might want to rethink, and have a `HashMap` from strings to nodes.

Comment: well sh*t, ah well I will consider this and find a way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if the ArrayList contains a certain instance of the INode class.  However, you don't define how to compare tow INodes.  ArrayList.contains() uses the INode class's default .equals() method, which will not actually work unless it is overriden using @Override in the INode class.  If you are using Eclipse, you can easily generate the .equals() and .hashCode() functions by pressing Alt+Shift+S and selecting "Generate hashcode() and equals()